# Force InfoPath Form to open in client in SharePoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-online, infopath

We just migrated from SP 2010 to SP Online.

I've got an InfoPath form that is set in the form to open in the InfoPath client.

In the 2010 environment, I have a hyperlink to fill out a new InfoPath form, and a "New Item" button in the toolbar at the top of a view of the form library embedded in a page. I have the library settings set to "Open in client", and the library set to "classic".

If I am on the library itself, the form opens in the client as expected. If I click on the hyperlink to create a new form, or click the button on the embedded view, I get an error when SP tries to open the form in a browser window, even when I add the `?DefaultItemOpen=0` parameter.

```
https://somesite.sharepoint.com/Sites/AAA/Office/Division/Branch/Forms/Waiver.xsn?DefaultItemOpen=0
```

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

You could try the link like this:

```
https://tenant.sharepoint.com/sites/michael/_layouts/15/FormServer.aspx?XmlLocation=/sites/michael/Formlibrary/1.xml
```